# Converting timestamp from CET / CEST to UTC

Tags: c#, datetime, timezone

I am currently writing a tool which parses files that have a custom, non-standard file format.
The files contain data for several measuring points with timestamps (one measurement every 30 seconds). Those timestamps are in the CET / CEST time zone which means that when the time for example changes from summer to winter time, there will be multiple measurements with the same timestamp in the file because every timestamp between 2:00 and 3:00 in the morning will exist twice in the file (one from before and one from after the time changed).

I am already able to parse all the timestamp data I need (year, month, day, hours and minutes) from the file but I also need to convert it to UTC.
Is there any functionality in the .NET Framework or in a 3rd party library to do this conversion?

I already tried using `TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc` but I already need to have a DateTime object for that which I don't know how to create yet.
I cannot simply create a new DateTime object using one of the DateTime-constructors because lets say I provide one of the timestamps which exists twice in a file because of a change from summer to winter time - How will it know if the timestamp is from before or after the time changed?

I thought that this is probably a somewhat common problem when dealing with timestamps but I was not able to find any good solution for my problem yet. Do I need to manually keep track of when the time change happens in a file in order to convert the time to UTC correctly? If so, how can I do that?

UPDATE:
Here is a very simplified example of the problem that I am trying to solve:
This could be some of the data that my tool has parsed from the timestamps in the file:

```
Day: 27 - Month: 10 - Year: 2019 - Hour: 1 - Minute: 45 - Second: 0 
Day: 27 - Month: 10 - Year: 2019 - Hour: 2 - Minute: 0 - Second: 0 
Day: 27 - Month: 10 - Year: 2019 - Hour: 2 - Minute: 15 - Second: 0 
Day: 27 - Month: 10 - Year: 2019 - Hour: 2 - Minute: 30 - Second: 0 
Day: 27 - Month: 10 - Year: 2019 - Hour: 2 - Minute: 45 - Second: 0 
Day: 27 - Month: 10 - Year: 2019 - Hour: 2 - Minute: 0 - Second: 0 
Day: 27 - Month: 10 - Year: 2019 - Hour: 2 - Minute: 15 - Second: 0 
Day: 27 - Month: 10 - Year: 2019 - Hour: 2 - Minute: 30 - Second: 0 
Day: 27 - Month: 10 - Year: 2019 - Hour: 2 - Minute: 45 - Second: 0 
Day: 27 - Month: 10 - Year: 2019 - Hour: 3 - Minute: 0 - Second: 0 
Day: 27 - Month: 10 - Year: 2019 - Hour: 3 - Minute: 15 - Second: 0 
Day: 27 - Month: 10 - Year: 2019 - Hour: 3 - Minute: 30 - Second: 0
```

(in reality there is much more data per hour but this doesn't matter for the example)

In this example, the clock is set one hour back from 3:00 to 2:00 in the morning because Daylight Saving Time ends here and therefore we change from CEST to CET.
The opposite thing happens ~6 months later (and obviously also 6 months earlier) when the Daylight Saving Time period begins and the clock is moved forward by one hour.

There is no indication whatsoever in the files that my tool parses about wether a timestamp is in CET or CEST so my parsing logic needs to handle this.
I basically have a loop which iterates over the rows in the file, parses the timestamps and then calls this function to get a DateTime-object for each timestamp:

```
private static DateTime toDateTimeUTC(int year, int month, int day, int hour, int minute, int second)
{
    // ToDo

    return new DateTime(year, month, day, hour, minute, second, DateTimeKind.Utc); // This is WRONG!
}
```

This code obviously does not work correctly so far because it just assumes that the timestamps are in UTC.

Comment: Can you please provide some sample timestamps (from your file) and your parsing logic?

Comment: @PeterCsala Why? I have a year, month, day, minute and second parsed from a CET / CEST timestamp and I need to create a UTC DateTime-object from that. How is the file structure and parsing logic relevant for the problem that I am trying to solve? I do not want to go into detail about the file structure because it is quite complex and confusing.

Comment: @Chris - You'll likely need to use other `TimeZoneInfo` methods including `IsAmbiguousTime` and `GetAmbiguousTimeOffsets`, along with your own logic for disambiguating. Would love to help you here, but for this type of problem, we really need to see some data and code to be able to help you.  If your existing code is too complex, then please provide code that illustrates your problem.  Please read [*How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) from the Stack Overflow help center.  Thanks.

Comment: (At minimum, provide an example of the data you are working with, so people do not have to guess.)

Comment: @MattJohnson-Pint I just updated the question and added an example. Please let me know if that helps.

Comment: "There is no indication whatsoever in the files that my tool parses about whether a timestamp is in CET or CEST so my parsing logic needs to handle this." How could your parsing logic handle this in the most general case? If you have a file with a single log entry, and that's ambiguous, you're basically missing information. I can see how if your file has entries which suddenly go back an hour, in *that* case you can say "everything before then is in DST, everything after then is in standard time" but there are various ways you might not have that information.

Comment: @JonSkeet The files contain data for exactly 1 day per file. I know that this is impossible to do in the most general case but I will implement it assuming that there is always enough data to see when it goes back or forth an hour. There is nothing else I can do because this is the data that I got and I need to work with. If possible, I want some sort of error-handling or warning in my code, just in case that it parses a file that is missing important information/context that the tool needs to identify the time zone of one or more timestamps in the file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know you'll always have one day per file, and you can always detect the change because you're recording data every 30 seconds, you can spot when the local timestamp goes backwards, and work out which ambiguous offset to use that way. Something like this:

```cs
TimeZoneInfo zone = ...; // I assume you've got this already
bool afterFallBack = false;
DateTime previousUnspecifiedTimestamp = DateTime.MinValue;
foreach (var line in log)
{
    var timestampText = ...; // Take the timestamp from the line
    // Parse the timestamp without performing any time zone conversions
    // (The "unspecified" part of the name refers to the DateTimeKind.Unspecified.)
    // TODO: Check the format
    var unspecifiedTimestamp = DateTime.ParseExact(timestampText,
        "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss", timestampText, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

    // Detect "fall back" so we know which 
    if (unspecifiedTimestamp < previousUnspecifiedTimestamp)
    {
        afterFallBack = true;
    }
    previousUnspecifiedTimestamp = unspecifiedTimestamp;

    DateTime utcTimestamp = ConvertToZone(zone, unspecifiedTimestamp, afterFallBack);
    // Process the log entry
}

// Method extracted for testability and tidiness
private static DateTime ConvertToZone(
    TimeZoneInfo zone, DateTime dateTime, bool useLaterAmbiguousOffset)
{
    if (!zone.IsAmbiguousTime(dateTime))
    {
        return TimeZoneInfo.ConvertToUtc(dateTime, zone);
    }
    // The offsets returned by this appear to be in order of "smallest offset"
    // to "largest offset" - which means that the offset that's observed later is 
    // the one that occurs at the start of the array. This isn't actually
    // documented... you could order the offsets for added certainty,
    // but I'd be surprised if this changed.
    var offsets = zone.GetAmbiguousTimeOffsets(dateTime);
    var chosenOffset = useLaterAmbiguousOffset ? offsets[0] : offset[1];
    return DateTime.SpecifyKind(dateTime - chosenOffset, DateTimeKind.Utc);
}
```

As an aside, this code would IMO be simpler with my [Noda Time](https://nodatime.org) project, but I wouldn't necessarily recommend that you switch over just for the sake of this. If you're doing any significant amount of date/time work, it would be worth a look.

Comment: Thanks! I think you need to switch the offsets when assigning the offset to chosenOffset. Other than that, I managed to implement this similar to your example and it now seems to work perfectly!

Comment: @Chris: Hmm... I'd assumed that the offsets would be returned in the order in which they were effective, but maybe not... will investigate. Anyway, glad it worked out for you :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have everything in DateTimeOffset with +1/+2 based on summer/winter then you just save the ToUniversalTime if you want to save it with Offset +0.

```
var input = new DateTimeOffset(2000,1,1,23,59,00, TimeSpan.FromHours(1));
var utc = cet.ToUniversalTime();
```

Comment: But I don't have anything in a DateTimeOffset object? The problem here is to actually figure out the offset, not to convert it to UTC.

Comment: @Chris you cannot get code that figures out the offset, you have to loop and switch when times switch. How is code that doesn't have the metadata know if a time is CEST or CET? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summer_time_in_Europe have a table of dates.